# How to find an expression in a text file and process all lines until the next occurrence of the expression and repeat until end of the file

Tags: ruby, parsing, text

I have a text file:

```
Some comment on the 1st line of the file.

processing date:         31.8.2016
amount:                  -1.23
currency:                EUR
balance:                 1234.56
payer reference:         /VS123456/SS0011223344/KS1212
type of the transaction: Some type of the transaction 1
additional info:         Amount: 1.23 EUR 29.08.2016 Place: 123456789XY



processing date:         30.8.2016
amount:                  -2.23
currency:                EUR
balance:                 12345.56
payer reference:         /VS123456/SS0011223344/KS1212
type of the transaction: Some type of the transaction 2
additional info:         Amount: 2.23 EUR 28.08.2016 Place: 123456789XY



processing date:         29.8.2016
amount:                  -3.23
currency:                EUR
balance:                 123456.56
payer reference:         /VS123456/SS0011223344/KS1212
type of the transaction: Some type of the transaction 2
additional info:         Amount: 2.23 EUR 27.08.2016 Place: 123456789XY
```

I need to process the file so I will have the values on the right side, `31.8.2016`, `-1.23`, `EUR`, `1234.56`, etc., stored in a MySQL database.

I only achieved returning either 1 occurrence of the line which contains a particular string or all the lines using [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) or [`find_all`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-find_all), but this is not sufficient as I somehow need to identify the block starting with "processing date:" and ending with "additional info:" and process the values there, then process next block, and next, until the end of the file.

Any hints how to achieve this?

Comment: that could be done in several ways,but the most simple way is to read whole file as string, call `.split(/^processing date/)` on that and you will get a list of segments starting by the date and ending with empty newlines that are present before next item. It is simple, but may fail if your files are *large* like, gigabytes.

Comment: Your question is premature. You need to try, then when you run into a problem write a detailed question about that specific problem. Please read "[ask]" and the linked pages, and "[mcve]". Also "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261593/128421)" will help you understand what we expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd start with this:

```
File.foreach('data.txt', "\n\n") do |li|
  next unless li[/^processing/]
  puts "'#{li.strip}'"
end
```

If "data.txt" contains your content, `foreach` will read the file and return paragraphs, not lines, of text in `li`. Once you have those you can manipulate them as you need. This is very fast and efficient and doesn't have the scalability problems `readlines` or any `read`-based I/O could have.

This is the output:

```
'processing date:         31.8.2016
amount:                  -1.23
currency:                EUR
balance:                 1234.56
payer reference:         /VS123456/SS0011223344/KS1212
type of the transaction: Some type of the transaction 1
additional info:         Amount: 1.23 EUR 29.08.2016 Place: 123456789XY'
'processing date:         30.8.2016
amount:                  -2.23
currency:                EUR
balance:                 12345.56
payer reference:         /VS123456/SS0011223344/KS1212
type of the transaction: Some type of the transaction 2
additional info:         Amount: 2.23 EUR 28.08.2016 Place: 123456789XY'
'processing date:         29.8.2016
amount:                  -3.23
currency:                EUR
balance:                 123456.56
payer reference:         /VS123456/SS0011223344/KS1212
type of the transaction: Some type of the transaction 2
additional info:         Amount: 2.23 EUR 27.08.2016 Place: 123456789XY'
```

You can see by the wrapping `'` that the file is being read in chunks or paragraphs delineated by `"\n\n"` then each chunk is stripped to remove trailing blanks.

See the `foreach` documentation for more information.

`split(':', 2)` is your friend:

```
'processing date:         31.8.2016'.split(':', 2) # => ["processing date", "         31.8.2016"]
'amount:                  -1.23'.split(':', 2) # => ["amount", "                  -1.23"]
'currency:                EUR'.split(':', 2) # => ["currency", "                EUR"]
'balance:                 1234.56'.split(':', 2) # => ["balance", "                 1234.56"]
'payer reference:         /VS123456/SS0011223344/KS1212'.split(':', 2) # => ["payer reference", "         /VS123456/SS0011223344/KS1212"]
'type of the transaction: Some type of the transaction 1'.split(':', 2) # => ["type of the transaction", " Some type of the transaction 1"]
'additional info:         Amount: 1.23 EUR 29.08.2016 Place: 123456789XY'.split(':', 2) # => ["additional info", "         Amount: 1.23 EUR 29.08.2016 Place: 123456789XY"]
```

From that you can do:

```
text = 'processing date:         31.8.2016
amount:                  -1.23
currency:                EUR
balance:                 1234.56
payer reference:         /VS123456/SS0011223344/KS1212
type of the transaction: Some type of the transaction 1
additional info:         Amount: 1.23 EUR 29.08.2016 Place: 123456789XY'

text.lines.map{ |li| li.split(':', 2).map(&:strip) }.to_h
# => {"processing date"=>"31.8.2016", "amount"=>"-1.23", "currency"=>"EUR", "balance"=>"1234.56", "payer reference"=>"/VS123456/SS0011223344/KS1212", "type of the transaction"=>"Some type of the transaction 1", "additional info"=>"Amount: 1.23 EUR 29.08.2016 Place: 123456789XY"}
```

There are a number of ways to continue parsing the information into more usable data but that's for you to figure out.

Comment: Thanks! I will check this.